# How to get text to loop infinitely (without 'restarting') but displays in 3 columns above it's breakpoints

Tags: html, text, scroll

Hopefully this makes sense... I'm somewhat self taught so apologies if my terminology isn't correct... here goes.

I'm trying to display some product USPs that will display as text in 3 columns until the page width gets down to say 900px. Below this, I want the text to revert to scrolling across the page. I've got this bit functioning so far.

However the text will scroll across the page and then almost 'replay'. There will be a big gap between column 3 making it's way off the left edge and the scroll starting over again. I want this text to just repeat, so column 3 will be followed by column 1 with the same sized gap as 1-2 and 2-3.

This is what I've done so far and it'll do the job but I'd like that scrolling bar piece of text to act more naturally.

```
<style>
.container {
  background-color: #F7F7F7;
  font-family: "DM Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 10pt;
  line-height: 0.75;
  display: flex;
  gap: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;

}

.column {
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 33%;
}

/* Animation */
@keyframes scroll {
  0% { transform: translateX(0%); }
  100% { transform: translateX(-100%); }
}

@media (max-width: 900px) {
  .container {
    animation: scroll 60s linear infinite;
    display: flex;
    width: 1400px;
  }
}
</style>

<div class="container">
  <div class="column">
    <p>   | 30 Day Risk Free Returns</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <p>  | Guaranteed up to 5 years</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <p>  | Wash. Dry. Use. Repeat.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```